# How to read float element from txt file and add them?

Tags: python, file, floating-point

i have txt file with lot of float number like this

```
0.0011057552 0.0024052237 0.0012284562 0.002244099 0.0019317493 0.0016500594 0.0015984756 0.0028826133 0.0018553216 0.0015231475 0.0006213288
```

right now i am doing

```
file = open("abc.txt" ,mode='r')
text1 = file.read()
text1.replace("\n"," ")
total = 0.0
list1=list(text1.split(' '))
for num in list1:
    total= total + float(num)
```

but its giving me error like **total= total + float(num)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''**

what should I do ?

Comment: Re-assign the result. `text1 = text1.replace("\n"," ")` or just add it after `read()`

Comment: @GeneralGrievance now this error is there---- total= total + float(num)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242961/discussion-between-spartex-and-general-grievance).

Comment: No need. Please update your sample data so that the code you posted reproduces your issue.

Comment: Use `str.strip()` to remove spaces at the ends of your string.